# Second Largest Cell Value (ignoring duplicates)

Tags: google-sheets

to put it in short words, I need the string "Jordan" as a result (cell G3). Please see my sheet below.

```
Row 1:   A     | B     | C      | D      | E     | F      | G      | H     | I
Row 2:   NAME1 | TEXT1 | VALUE1 | NAME2  | TEXT2 | VALUE3 | NAME3  | TEXT3 | VALUE3
Row 3:   Jack  | KCC   | 500    | Marvin | KCD   | 100    | Jordan | KCE   | 500
Row 4:   ...
```

More precise: I am able to retrieve "JACK" being the name with the largest value, seen from the left. But I need the name string of the second highest value ("JORDAN"), even if the both highest values may be identical and equal 500.

Any help with Google Sheets would be appreciated!!

Best,
David

Comment: Can you detail your question a bit more? By which criteria do you decide that "Jack" is the highest value? What are your search criteria? Are you looking for a content within your whole table (or within a certain row) that is a string and not a number and that comes alphabetically second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the formula, must be modified if any change of your columns data:

```
= array_constrain(Sort({A3:C3;D3:F3;G3:I3},3,false, 1, false),1,3)
```

[image]

or as follow (Col1 First, Col2 Second and Col3 Last Largest)

```
= transpose(query(transpose(Sort({A3:C3;D3:F3;G3:I3},3,false)),"select Col2",0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will have a look into this and send a response.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution: Next level Google sheets. :-) Thank you so much!